# Store session using Javascript display in label in another page in ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session

Is there any way to store a session using javascript variable and display on a label on another page? I'm using ASP.NET WebForms C#.

Thanks.

Comment: how are you planning to store this session? if you have an input element, then set its value to that session and pull it via javascript and save it to a variable

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [ask] then update question with complete details of what you are trying to do

Comment: you can't store a session variable directly using JS. Session is a server-side concept, JS is client-side. If you want to set a variable using JS that can be passed to the server (and the server can store it in the session) then you can either put the variable in a form element and post back, or use ajax. Alternatively, if you just need to pass the variable directly to the next page, maybe a hyperlink with the variable in the querystring would be sufficient. Like charlie said, tells us the full details of what you want to achieve, without reference to a specific method of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "session" - as in "managed by ____".

- As commented above, "sessions" can be managed by the **server** (safer, particularly if you want to have "full control" over what data be persisted)
- but it's not the "only" place you can create "sessions". See [WebStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), if your needs can live on the **client** side of things.

  Stating the obvious, it's *client side* so it can be manipulated (trivially) by the user/client so just like anything coming from the client, never trust (**always** validate/check).

---

Trivial example (must improve):

In some `_Layout` page (or master page, or some Javascript library for your site):

```
var ClientSession = function() {

    this.setItem = function(key, value) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    this.getItem = function(key) {
        return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    }
}

var mySessionBroker = new ClientSession();
```

In some other page where you set `items` for the *duration of the browser session*

```
<script>       

    window.mySessionBroker.setItem("key1", "hello from Index page");

    //At this point, you should see that you can store something generated from the server 
    //and manage it from that point forward in javascript/client like so:
    window.mySessionBroker.setItem("key2", "<%=HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(SomeServerVariable) %>");

</script>
```

In any other page on your site (same domain/protocol) where you want to use/display, etc. items set in `sessionStorage`

```
<p>Session data: <input id="someInput" name="foo" /></p>


<script>

    window.onload = function() {
        var target = document.getElementById("someInput");
        target.value = window.mySessionBroker.getItem("key1");
    }


</script>
```

You can use browser dev tools to inspect both `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` (goes without saying that as above, if *you* can, *anyone else* can - hence validate/inspect and **don't use it for sensitive items**).

Hth..

Comment: If `SomeServerVariable` ultimately comes from the user or a third party, there is an issue of code injection here. Use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` on the variable before inserting its value in the page as part of executed javascript.

Comment: @NineBerry Agreed - thanks!